Do lawn signs really work?
Before election day in many places you'll see signs galore on the side of the road and in front of houses trying to influence passers-by to vote for certain people or amendments. Is there any evidence that these signs actually work? Specifically in the massive races, such as president, where chances are most passers-by know of the existance of the two major candidates, and you don't have the potential logic a person seeing 2 options and voting for the only one he's heard of, like you might be local races. And also in cases of amendments which are often referred to only by their number with no description on the sign -- is anyone being influenced to (for example) "vote yes on 3" just because someone's lawn says to do so?

I've tagged this with US since in many other countries there isn't such a custom. And, yeah, I agree it's the same Q that was asked before.
